# Monotouch Sqlite-net or ADO.Net

Tags: sqlite, ado.net, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

I would like to use Sqlite database in my Monotouch app. From    http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/data/sqlite i see two options.

1. Sqlite-net
2. ADO.NET

Doing research i found that Sqlite-net is easy to use, works on both ios and android but does not support foreign key concept. My need is to have relations in my db. Student table is linked to classes, professor, assignments table. Not so complicated!!!
Does Sqlite-net supports such relations? Which one is better choice Sqlite-net or ADO.Net.
Appreciated...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.Net doesn't give you out of the box support for relationships either. It only gives you raw classes like `SQLCommand` and `SQLDataReader`.

I would highly recommend sqlite-net, as it is a huge timesaver in being an ORM.

You can setup foreign keys by calling manual SQL statements in sqlite-net, which is the same you would do with ADO.Net anyway.

So with sqlite-net, there are several ways you could setup your database:

1. Call sqlite-net's APIs for creating tables based on your C# classes, then add things it doesn't support with manual SQL like foreign keys and indexes
2. Include an empty database with your app with the full schema already setup
3. Create the entire database with a raw SQL script

I tend to go with option #2 if I want full control of the database schema (and it's a little easier to include a database file I made in SQLite Expert).  sqlite-net should work with an existing database just fine.

Comment: Unless you literally know nothing about SQL and schemas I'd be wary of (1) also, as I've had no end of problems caused by developers using this approach and not knowing/understanding what schema this has been turned into.
Also, any idea what happens when you need to update the schema, such as add a new field to a table?  If you add a field to the class what happens to the old data, as it might be an app version update it's being added for?

Comment: Yes, I usually go with #2 and then have had to roll my own migration plan for schema changes. [SQLiteExpert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/) is a great tool for creating databases ahead of time.